# Cannot connect to ExtProc In Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

We have two Oracle instances on one server (both 11g) that are using the same listener.  I am having an issue with connecting to the extproc:

TNSNAMES.ORA

```
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA.NATIONAL.SERVER.COM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC11G))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc11g)
    )
  )
```

LISTENER.ORA

```
(DESCRIPTION_LIST=
    (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST=
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC11G))
     )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc11g)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY")
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
```

When I use TNSPING to check the connection, I get the following:

/home/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

$tnsping EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 03-NOV-2011 14:03:41

Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC11G))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc11g)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

I am able successfully tnsping both of the databases but not the EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA.

Comment: I have noticed that the IPC is not showing up in the Listening Endpoints Summary when lsnrctl status is run:

    Listening Endpoints Summary...
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)            (HOST=qatb1a.national.aaa.com)(PORT=1521)))
    Services Summary...
    Service "PLSExtProc11g" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "PLSExtProc11g", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s)         for this service...
.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case there was apparently some type of hidden character in the listener.ora file.  Using netca to reconfigure the listener resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change the SID_NAME with the correct value, It may solve the issue.

example:
 (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc11g)
   to 
 (SID_NAME = ORCL)